# VSTS CI Build not being able to find Nuget Packages on Restore

Tags: asp.net-core, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines-build-task, asp.net-core-2.0

We have just developed a fully working Visual Studio Team Services Continuous Integration when issues started to arise.

I've done a lot of digging but couldn't find any potential solutions.

We are building a .NET Core 2.0 WebApi solution and are using project Nuget packages instead of project references which we upload to https://myget.org/. The current impediment is that once the build reaches the Restore phase, it stops because it cannot find some of the packages.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Packages are incremented with a different version number every time there are changes, therefore they need to be built. Yes, but you cannot set a Build solution task before the restoration task and you cannot set the Nuget Packages Publisher to MyGet before the Restoration task because there will no packages to actually upload (since they are not built).

Is there a way we could run a post-build event script which can be executed on the Restore command builds packages? Is writing a PowerShell script a solution? Open to any kind of suggestions.

Comment: Since you need to restore packages from myget.org for later times, you just need to **add the initial version of packages to myget.org before the first time to build**, then you can update packages in the later tasks. When the CI build is triggered again, nuget restore can download the higher version of packages. And in the Nuegt restore step, you should specify the nuget.config file you used.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT I guess I didn't explain that pretty well in my post or I didn't mention it at all. We are not restoring the packages from myget.org. They are restored locally. That's why when I tried to restore some of the packages, the build definition could not find them cause they were not triggered by the build of the solution.

Comment: I managed to find the solution to the problem - simply create a separate build definition, a replica of the current solution which builds the packages of all projects, runs the unit tests and then publishes them to MyGet.org. After a dozen builds of troubleshooting, all of the packages were uploaded to the myget repository successfully.